# What is the best self-guided itinerary for an 8-day trip to Scotland in April?

Tags: itineraries, scotland, self-guided

We're trying to plan a budget-minded trek to Scotland in April during school holiday and are wondering if we should simply rent a car and try our luck at B&B's or go the pre-planned route.

Comment: Hi Kathi and welcome to Travel.SE.  Currently your question is a bit open and can't easily be answered objectively.  What is "the best"?? If you could perhaps reword and indicate what you'd like to see - be it mountain climbing, staking out Loch Ness, or pub hopping - each person would have a different opinion of what is "the best".

Comment: no change and author hasn't returned since 16th of Jan, so I'm closing.  However, @Kathi, if you do come back and edit it, we'd be happy to reopen it and help you answer the question! :)

Comment: YOu've made a good start by talking about your budget and transportation options. You can clarify the question more by telling of your interests (nature, art, whatever), and your group composition (just two adults, or three generations).